Javascript array.join returns empty value on array of strings
(I'm pretty new to javascript so sorry if this is rather obvious!)
My code pulls artist ids from spotify's api and stores them as strings in an array. I need to concatenate them into a string seperated by commas, so I tried to use array.join.
let artistIds = [];
spotify.getMyTopArtists().then(
  (data) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      const str = data.body.items[i].id
      artistIds.push(str)
    }
  }
)
console.log(artistIds);
let str = artistIds.join(",");
console.log(str);

The spotify object is from the spotify-web-api-node library.
I though this would just concat the strings with commas in between, but the console output looks like this:


Your code is fine. You just need to move let str = artistIds.join(","); and console.log(str); inside the then() callback directly after the for loop. You are already doing asynchronous code.
